# t-sql how to create a trigger that joins 2 servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, triggers, instances

I am trying to complete a trigger on 2 instances of SQL Server. I am running MS Dynamics ERP set CRM & GP. I need to remove data from one server once an update happens to another table. I have written a script that will complete this task if I have the 2 DBs on the same instance. But, when I try to invoke the other server by modifying the code, I just get errors.

I have a table on server SQL12\CRM instance CRM_MSCRM DB. And, the other is located on server SQL12 main instance Comp1 DB. Here is my code:

```
USE [CRM_MSCRM]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trgDeleteEmpAccList_Weld]    Script Date:     7/31/2015 7:45:53 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgDeleteEmpAccList_Weld]

ON [dbo].[Cfs_jobBase]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE

AS

BEGIN

DELETE p
    FROM [SQL12].[CFSPR].[dbo].[PA01408] p
    INNER JOIN [CRM_MSCRM].[dbo].[Cfs_jobbase] j
    ON p.paprojnumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = j.cfs_jobnumber COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    INNER JOIN FROM [SQL12].[CFSPR].[dbo].[UPR00100] e
    ON p.EMPLOYID = e.employid

    WHERE (j.statuscode = 2 OR j.statuscode = 5) AND (e.DEPRTMNT = 'THERM' OR j.cfs_enddate <=DATEADD(day,-2,getdate()))

    PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
END

GO
```

I am getting an error of invalid object for Comp1 table items. I have added the other server as a linked server to try an bypass this issue, but still occurs.

Screenshot of underlining errors:

! [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUfbB.png

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: remove from FROM  innerjoin

Comment: Bad idea. If at all possible, have triggers queue work locally (using e.g. a table, or service broker, etc). Otherwise, you're usually taking a serious hit on availability/reliability.

Comment: Removing "FROM" worked!! Thanks Jonathan!

Comment: oh great it's worked but triggers on different servers not a good idea   @TrayS

Comment: Are you saying the only "error" you are seeing is that Management Studio is underlining the remote objects with red squigglies? That's just IntelliSense not able to see into the remote metadata. Ignore it or turn IntelliSense off. "Errors" are actual exceptions that occur when you run the code, not visual phenomena.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is Linked SQL Server. Easy to setup and allow to access linked server from one server.

Here is a link on how to setup this.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35943/How-to-Config-Linked-Servers-in-a-Minute

Then you can query linked server with [server].[database].[schema].[table].
For example : Select * FROM DatabaseServer1.db1.dbo.table1.

As other mentioned, watch out for performance hit. Join operation between local table and table of linked server is really slow. To speed up query, querying needed data on linked server into table variable is one way to go. Keek linked query as simple as possible.